# usg ufw conflict rules

Tags: security, firewall, ufw

I ran a usg audit (following https://ubuntu.com/blog/cis-security-compliance-usg)

`sudo usg audit cis_level1_server`

[See audit result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obu1e.png)

I don't understand what usg is trying to do with ufw.

First, package_ufw_installed rule installs it (`apt-get install ufw`) then package_ufw_removed  removes it (`apt-get remove ufw`).

I had a server with ufw enabled and running with systemd. Once I ran usg fix (`sudo usg fix cis_level1_server`), ufw has been removed and ufw service was masked. The rules service_ufw_enabled  (`sudo systemctl enable ufw.service`) pass while ufw is not running anymore. Then all ufw rules pass.

I reinstalled and enabled ufw then package_ufw_removed rule does not pass.

Please explain to me what usg is doing with firewall and ufw...

Should I let it uninstall ufw?

Answer (score 0):

I made some research, for I can see package_ufw_installed and package_ufw_removed rules address to different situations.

package_ufw_installed applied when using iptbables (CIS§3.5.1.1) while package_ufw_removed concerns servers using nftables (CIS§3.5.2.2). (https://downloads.cisecurity.org/#/)

It is strange than usg try to apply both while my server is not using nftables...

I guess I need to make a custom profile on usg to makeb sure it won't uninstall ufw.